# MediaPlayer stream doesn't work on Galaxy SII

Tags: android, stream, android-mediaplayer

My client says stream doesn't work for him and he is on Galaxy SII. I don't know why, it works for me.

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    player.setDataSource("http://radijas.tau.lt:8000/stream");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
}
});
//...
player.prepareAsync();
player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
{
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        player.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.

Comment: why always everything works on my device and not on client's device?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the data source. Others work fine.

Comment: @user3249477 do you have any idea what might be wrong?